# How to compare array mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently building a cart system on my mongodb ecommerce app. I need help on how to query and compare array.

here document of cart:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0531e27c8fa1029017ea20"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5d0371319315c715fc34b0b0"),
    "active" : true,
    "item" : [ 
        {
            "product" : ObjectId("5d013eb63a2bdd11a46c8dd3"),
            "option" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Ukuran",
                    "value" : "Biru"
                }
            ],
            "quantity" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "product" : ObjectId("5d013eb63a2bdd11a46c8dd3"),
            "option" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Ukuran",
                    "value" : "Biru"
                }
            ],
            "quantity" : 1
        }
    ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-06-15T17:58:58.762Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-06-15T17:59:13.334Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to compare object of item.option field, so my cart system is if cart on database have same object option i will add quantity, otherwise push new object to item.

so current I am not asking on how to implement my cart system, but I want to compare each item.option object

I've already tried this

```
const cart = await CartModel.find({
    "item.option": option
})
```

and get error `Error: Query filter must be an object, got an array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself, after many experiment finally i combine $in and $elemMatch for compare each array of object

```
// this is will dynamic
const optionArray = [
   {
      "name": "Warna",
      "value": "Biru"
   },
   {
      "name": "Ukuran",
      "value": "XL"
   }
]

const compareOptionQuery = []

for (let i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
   compareOptionQuery.push({
      $elemMatch: {
         ...option[i]
      }
   })
}

const cart = await CartModel.aggregate([
  {
     $and: [
        {
           _id: cartId,
           user: userId
        },
        {
          'item.option': {
            $in: [...compareOptionQuery]
          }
        }
     ]
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your implementation is that in `CartModel.find("item.option": option)` your filter (first parameter) encounters an array instead of an object.

This is because you are trying to call for an object `option` from `item`, however `option` is as element of an ***array field*** `item`.

If you wish to access `item` from an array field, you must specify conditions on the elements in the array field `item` using `{<array field>: {<operator1>: <value1>}}` like so:

```
CartModel.find({
   item: {$option: option}
})
```

Comment: because is my problem, the option object are dynamic i cannot specify field manual

Comment: Regardless of array length/dynamicness, the above implementation should find you the element with the corresponding option. What are you unable to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  i solve myself problem after trying trying and trying. Look at this https://pastebin.com/HnhW5YW8